# Adding JScrollPane to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add a JScrollPane to an JPanel from a separate class. And thanks to some questions, which were asked so far, I could help myself create them. But my problem is still a little bit special.
I want to display an image on a JPanel and if the image is to large for the panel, I want to add scrollbars. But the scrollbars won't appear.
(When I set the `ScrollPaneConstants` to `****_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` the frame of the bar appears, but without the bars to scroll).

I guess i have to connect the imagesize with the bars, so that they appear?

Some pieces of my code:

MainWindow

```
public class Deconvolutioner extends JFrame
{
Draw z;
Picturearea picturearea;

class Draw extends JPanel
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

    }
}

public Deconvolutioner()
{
    setTitle("Deconvolutioner");
    setLocation(30,1);
    setSize(1300,730);
    super.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,11));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);

    this.setLayout(flow);

    picturearea = new Picturearea();
    picturearea.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(picturearea, 
    ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
    ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 664));

    getContentPane().add(scrollPane, flow); // add scrollpane to frame


    add(z = new Draw());
    setVisible(true);

}
}
```

JPanel Class

```
public class Picturearea extends JPanel
{
BufferedImage image;
int panelWidth, panelHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight;

public Picturearea()
{
    setBackground(new Color(210,210,210));
    setBorder(LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder());


    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

}

public void setPicture(BufferedImage picture)
{
    try 
    {                
        image = picture;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.err.println("Some IOException accured (did you set the right path?): ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    repaint();
}

}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the JScrollPane has no way to know if it should display scroll bars or not, since the Picturearea it contains doesn't tell anything about its preferred size (or rather, it returns the preferred size based on its layout and on the components it contains. But since it doesn't contain any component, the returned preferred size is probably `(0, 0)`).

I would simply use a JLabel instead of the custom Picturearea class. A JLabel can display an image just fine, and it returns the appropriate Dimension when asked for its preferred size.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
But i have to perform mathematical calculations on these pictures.
i want to include some filter and have to work with the pixels and stuff like that. So i guess a label won't be Sufficient.

Comment: JPanel contains only Graphics return zero Dimension, override getPreferredSize (search here, maybe daily mentioned)

Comment: setBackground(new Color(210,210,210)); and setVisible(true); and  repaint(); are useless code lines,

Comment: @Kyrill, why JLabel won't do ?, the one component(`which is itself a JComponent`) that responds with image size and fit itself. Can you please enlighten me?

Comment: I see, you're right. I will use the label as an display item of my picture. I've included a label and it respond exactly as planned :)
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JLabel first and then add the Label to JPanel picturearea before creating instance for JScrollPane .

Have a try and it will work.

Example code is as follows:

```
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("d:\\099.jpg"));
    picturearea.add(imageLabel);**

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(picturearea,
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.
But i have to perform mathematical calculations on these pictures.
i want to include some filter and have to work with the pixels and stuff like that. So i guess a label won't be Sufficient.

Comment: Why not? Once you have your new image, you re-set the icon of the label, and you're done.

Comment: yes, you're right. I will use the label as an display item after the calculations are done :)
thanks for the tipp